# Gridview is not displaying expected results when databinding

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

When databinding my gridview from data stored in my database I am seeing a small square appear instead of the expected gridview results.

[image: Image of unexpected result]

The code I'm using:

```
 try
        {

               DataTable dsDetalle = new DataTable("Data");
            using (MySqlCommand commandSql = cn.CreateCommand())
            {
                commandSql.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                commandSql.CommandText = "select * from detalle where iddetalle=@iddetalle and idlocal=@idlocal";
                commandSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iddetalle", "txt_boleta.Text");
                commandSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idlocal", "txtlocal.Text");
                MySqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new  MySqlDataAdapter(commandSql);
                sqlAdapter.Fill(dsDetalle);
            }
            GridView1.DataSource = dsDetalle;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            lblerror.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: What have you tried when debugging this? For example the first thing I'd do is inspect the data table to ensure that things are being stored as expected, and if not follow the code before that.

Comment: thanks for correction  , yes i inspect the data and the query its ok

Comment: Can you show the GridView code from the aspx page? Maybe it is in there...

Comment: <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" style="margin-left: 0px"    >
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
             
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
        </asp:GridView>

Comment: thanks for help me i found the error @the Muffin Man have reaseon i got a problem in the query thanks for help : D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must omit quotes in the values of each parameter:

```
 using (MySqlCommand commandSql = cn.CreateCommand())
 {
    commandSql.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    commandSql.CommandText = "select * from detalle where iddetalle=@iddetalle and idlocal=@idlocal";
    commandSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iddetalle", txt_boleta.Text);
    commandSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idlocal", txtlocal.Text);
    MySqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new  MySqlDataAdapter(commandSql);
    sqlAdapter.Fill(dsDetalle);
 }
```

Also ensure you are opening the SQL connection and binding it with your SQL command

Comment: thanks for your aswner , i erase the qotes but have the same error :/